# Fatal error: while enabling AT theme

Tags: theming

I tried to enable AT theme and now have a white page with the error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/includes/theme.inc on line 98`

I changed my **php.ini** `memory_limit = 128M`. No difference.

I am so crazy pressed for time, this is the worst thing to happen now. How can i fix this?
Please somebody HELP!!!!!

The site is on a localhost.

PS- now i see a different error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/sites/all/modules/ds/includes/ds.registry.inc on line 554
```

Drupal 7.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 128M of memory is still not enough, try more. If that still fails there's probably a memory leak or endless loop somewhere, or a too bloated configuration (e.g. too many fields, trying to debug a structure that has too many entries and so on).

Comment: I had it set to 500 something, it made no difference.
I than followed Step 2 in https://drupal.org/node/200774  but still had the problem. 
Just tried setting to 1024, and WOW its working!
Thanks for the help!